# Join query between 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have three tables:

```
REGISTERS
------------------
id, name, idColony
------------------
1 , some, 3
2 , othe, 6
3 , sann, 3
------------------

EXTRA_COLONIES
------------------
id, idRegister, idColony
------------------
1,   1,   4
2,   1,   5
3,   2,   8
-----------------

COLONIES
------------------
1, some_colony
2, another_colony
...
...
```

I have a table called e.g. `REGISTER`.
This table will have an `idColony` (1 `idColony` is mandatory) from the `COLONIES` table.But this `REGISTERS` record/row can have up to 10 extra `idColony`s. That was the reason for me to separate to another table.

So the query I am doing is this:

```
SELECT table1.field,table2.field...
FROM (`REGISTERS`)
JOIN `EXTRA_COLONIES` ON `EXTRA_COLONIES`.`idRegister` = `REGISTERS`.`id`
WHERE (REGISTERS.idColony = '1' or EXTRA_COLONIES.idColony = '1')
GROUP BY `REGISTERS`.`id`
LIMIT 30
```

The problem with this query is that gets only the records that have `EXTRA_COLONIES`
because of the link `JOIN EXTRA_COLONIES ON EXTRA_COLONIES.idRegister = REGISTERS.id`.

How can I get all the records, `EXTRA_COLONIES` or not?

Comment: Replace `JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN` in your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` will solve the problem.

Irrespective of any matching `idRegister` in `EXTRA_COLONIES`, records from `REGISTER` should be returned

More on MySQL JOIN:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: That's the solution, Thank you both of you. I never used before left join and I never had the necessity to use it.